# Objective-C syntax issues

Tags: objective-c

I was just wondering what this line of code meant as I had never seen it before. Thanks in advance

```
- (NSString *)suit
{
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?";  /* precisely this part */
}
```

Comment: @JesseNk In this case, I advise you to learn C. Fully and properly. If you don't know C well, you will have **serious problems** with iOS development. C in itself is a lather big project to learn, and if you want to immediately jump into iOS development, Objective-C and the bloated Cocoa Touch API, you'll get lost fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a function called `suit` that returns an NSString.

This function will return _suit if _suit is not nil `(_suit ? _suit` does this.

Otherwise, it will return @"?" (the `:@"?"` does this).

the (something ? somethingElse : somethingElseAgain) just means if something is true, return somethingElse, otherwise return somethingElseAgain.

In other words, it is a simple, inline way to write:

```
if (something) {
    return somethingElse;
}
else {
    return somethingElseAgain;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSString *)suit
{
    if(_suit)
        return _suit;
    return @"?"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a). It is shorthand for

```
if (_suit)
    _suit;
else
    @"?";
```